# Where is my message queue producing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, mutex, message-queue

The message queue simply stops working when dealing with many many threads. It only seems to work okay with 10 threads, for exmaple. GDB tells me

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x7ffff78b0060 <_nl_global_locale>)
    at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
298 ../stdlib/strtol_l.c: No such file or directory.
```

But I have no idea what this means. The same code on Windows works fine but on linux it doesn't, which confuses me more.

You can see below how this queue works. It is a singly linked list with locking while receiving messages. Please help me find where I messed up.

```
typedef struct Message {
    unsigned type;
    unsigned code;
    void *data;
} Message;

typedef struct MessageQueueElement {
    Message message;
    struct MessageQueueElement *next;
} MessageQueueElement;

typedef struct MessageQueue {
    MessageQueueElement *first;
    MessageQueueElement *last;
} MessageQueue;

MessageQueue mq;
pthread_mutex_t emptyLock, sendLock;
pthread_cond_t emptyCond;

void init() {
    mq.first = malloc(sizeof(MessageQueueElement));
    mq.last = mq.first;
    pthread_mutex_init(&emptyLock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&sendLock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&emptyCond, NULL);
}

void clean() {
    free(mq.first);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&emptyLock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&sendLock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&emptyCond);
}

void sendMessage(MessageQueue *this, Message *message) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sendLock);
    if (this->first == this->last) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&emptyLock);
        this->last->message = *message;
        this->last = this->last->next = malloc(sizeof(MessageQueueElement));
        pthread_cond_signal(&emptyCond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&emptyLock);
    } else {
        this->last->message = *message;
        this->last = this->last->next = malloc(sizeof(MessageQueueElement));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sendLock);
}

int waitMessage(MessageQueue *this, int (*readMessage)(unsigned, unsigned, void *)) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&emptyLock);
    if (this->first == this->last) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&emptyCond, &emptyLock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&emptyLock);
    int n = readMessage(this->first->message.type, this->first->message.code, this->first->message.data);
    MessageQueueElement *temp = this->first;
    this->first = this->first->next;
    free(temp);
    return n;
}
```

**some test code:**

```
#define EXIT_MESSAGE 0
#define THREAD_MESSAGE 1
#define JUST_A_MESSAGE 2
#define EXIT 0
#define CONTINUE 1

int readMessage(unsigned type, unsigned code, void *data) {
    if (type == THREAD_MESSAGE) {
        printf("message from thread %d: %s\n", code, (char *)data);
        free(data);
    } else if (type == JUST_A_MESSAGE) {
        puts((char *)data);
        free(data);
    } else if (type == EXIT_MESSAGE) {
        puts("ending the program");
        return EXIT;
    }
    return CONTINUE;
}

int nThreads;
int counter = 0;

void *worker(void *p) {
    double pi = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) {
        pi += (4.0 / (8.0 * i + 1.0) - 2.0 / (8.0 * i + 4.0) - 1.0 / (8.0 * i + 5.0) - 1.0 / (8.0 * i + 6.0)) / pow(16.0, i);
    }
    char *s = malloc(100);
    sprintf(s, "pi equals %.8f", pi);
    sendMessage(&mq, &(Message){.type = THREAD_MESSAGE, .code = (int)(intptr_t)p, .data = s});
    counter += 1;
    char *s2 = malloc(100);
    sprintf(s2, "received %d message%s", counter, counter == 1 ? "" : "s");
    sendMessage(&mq, &(Message){.type = JUST_A_MESSAGE, .data = s2});
    if (counter == nThreads) {
        sendMessage(&mq, &(Message){.type = EXIT_MESSAGE});
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    clock_t timer = clock();
    init();
    nThreads = atoi(argv[1]);

    pthread_t threads[nThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i += 1) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)(intptr_t)i);
    }
    while (waitMessage(&mq, readMessage));
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i += 1) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    clean();
    timer = clock() - timer;
    printf("%.2f\n", (double)timer / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

--- EDIT ---
Okay I managed to fix the problem by changing the program a bit using semaphores. The `waitMessage` function doesn't have to be locked since it is accessed by only one thread and the values that it modifies does not clash with `sendMessage`.

```
MessageQueue mq;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t sem;

void init() {
    mq.first = malloc(sizeof(MessageQueueElement));
    mq.last = mq.first;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
}

void clean() {
    free(mq.first);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
}

void sendMessage(MessageQueue *this, Message *message) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    this->last->message = *message;
    this->last = this->last->next = malloc(sizeof(MessageQueueElement));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&sem);
}

int waitMessage(MessageQueue *this, int (*readMessage)(unsigned, unsigned, void *)) {
    sem_wait(&sem);
    int n = readMessage(this->first->message.type, this->first->message.code, this->first->message.data);
    MessageQueueElement *temp = this->first;
    this->first = this->first->next;
    free(temp);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your waitMessage function is modifying this->first outside of any locking. This is a bad thing.

It's often not worth recreating things that are already provided for you by an OS. You're effectively trying to set up a pipe of Message structures. You could simply use an anonymous pipe instead (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) for Linux, or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows) and write/read Message structures to/from it. There's also [POSIX message queues](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview) which are probably a bit more efficient.

In your case with multiple worker threads you'd have to have a supplementary mutex semaphore to control which worker is trying to read from the pipe or message queue.